# ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor...The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have been trying to create a multi-input model using Keras, but got errors. The idea is to combine the text and corresonding topics to make predictions for sentiments. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
text = np.random.randint(5000, size=(442702, 200), dtype='int32')
topic = np.random.randint(2, size=(442702, 227), dtype='int32')
sentiment = to_categorical(np.random.randint(5, size=442702), dtype='int32')

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Embedding, Flatten, GlobalMaxPool1D, Dropout, Conv1D
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import Adam


text_input = Input(shape=(200,), dtype='int32', name='text')
text_encoded = Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=20, input_length=200)(text_input)
text_encoded = Dropout(0.1)(text_encoded)
text_encoded = Conv1D(300, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(text_encoded)
text_encoded = GlobalMaxPool1D()(text_encoded)

topic_input = Input(shape=(227,), dtype='int32', name='topic')

concatenated = concatenate([text_encoded, topic_input])
sentiment = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(concatenated)

model = Model(inputs=[text_encoded, topic_input], outputs=sentiment)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
# plot graph
plot_model(model)
```

However, this gives me the below error:

`TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, int32] that don't all match.`

Now if I change dtype of topic_input from 'int32' to 'float32', I got a different error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("text_37:0", shape=(?, 200), dtype=int32) at layer "text". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

On the other hand, part of the model works just fine with the sequential API.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, 20, input_length=200))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Conv1D(300, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1))
model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(Dense(227))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

print(model.summary())
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't use `inputs=[text_input, topic_input]` instead of `inputs=[text_encoded, topic_input]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few issues with your Keras functional API implementation,

1. You should use the `Concatenate` layer as `Concatenate(axis=-1)([text_encoded, topic_input])`.
2. In the concatenate layer you are trying to combine an `int32` tensor and a `float32` tensor, which is not allowed. What you should do is, `from keras.backend import cast` and `concatenated = Concatenate(axis=-1)([text_encoded, cast(topic_input, 'float32')])`.
3. You got variable conflicts, there are two `sentiment` variables, one pointing to a `to_categorical` output and the other the output of the final `Dense` layer.
4. Your model inputs cannot be intermediate tensors like `text_encoded`. They should come from `Input` layers.

To help with your implementation, here's a working version of your code (I am not sure if this is exactly what you wanted though) in TF 1.13.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
text = np.random.randint(5000, size=(442702, 200), dtype='int32')
topic = np.random.randint(2, size=(442702, 227), dtype='int32')
sentiment1 = to_categorical(np.random.randint(5, size=442702), dtype='int32')

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation, Embedding, Flatten, GlobalMaxPool1D, Dropout, Conv1D, Concatenate, Lambda
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.backend import cast
from keras.models import Model

text_input = Input(shape=(200,), dtype='int32', name='text')
text_encoded = Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=20, input_length=200)(text_input)
text_encoded = Dropout(0.1)(text_encoded)
text_encoded = Conv1D(300, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(text_encoded)
text_encoded = GlobalMaxPool1D()(text_encoded)

topic_input = Input(shape=(227,), dtype='int32', name='topic')

topic_float = Lambda(lambda x:cast(x, 'float32'), name='Floatconverter')(topic_input)

concatenated = Concatenate(axis=-1)([text_encoded, topic_float])
sentiment = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(concatenated)

model = Model(inputs=[text_input, topic_input], outputs=sentiment)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

Hope these help.